# Unity classes handle in client side or serverside mostly?

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

Hi im quite confused as Unity tutorials and docs just say that for player network behaviors we have their class in the server but in client we're gonna have to create the classes too and save the info and or at least send packets or information for do the actions.
I'm messing around how in client vs server you just send a simple packet using UNet i mean with Send function i also added.

For example here is my function of send a single packet to a listening point:

Client Side:

```
void AuthenticateOnServer(AccountSession obj)
{
      _client.Send(0xff, obj);
}

void Connect()
{      
    _client = new NetworkClient();
    _client.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, DebugConnect);

    try
    {
        _client.Connect(ip, port);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
    }

    AuthenticateOnServer(acc);
}
```

Server Side:

```
NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(0xff, OnAuthentication); //its the handler
void OnAuthentication(NetworkMessage msg)
{
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Authentication token { {0} } from ID: {1} >",msg.ToString(),msg.conn.connectionId));

} //its the function handler
```

The opcode i mean the code waiting is 0xff and the obj but when i try to send and i already opened before the connection it says "NetworkClient Send with no connection".
What am i doing wrong or miss understanding ?

Comment: Where is the variable `acc` being set?

Comment: before both functions its the token retrieve for send as accountsession object

Comment: I've never done this in Unity3D before, but are you use that your client connection is being applied to your AccountSession?

Comment: Well account session just stands here for storage as a serialized object, the callbacks in server-side are made for listenning to opcodes or msgtypes comming in the way at that opcode and so on the client is sending it up as you can see but i get networkclient send with no connection and the connecting is made before i call the function

Comment: Try following the example in the script documentation page for [NetworkClient.Connect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkClient.Connect.html).  `Connect()` is probably an async operation so you should use the callbacks to handle your Authentication call after a successful connection.

Comment: I'm already doing it but does client need a handler for send message or we just proceed with Send() function?